# Game using html5 - Character jump with time limit

Tags: javascript, html

My explanation may be unclear and if so, please leave a comment for further clarification.

I am trying to make the character to jump to the height of the screen.
So far, this is my code:

```
 var limit = 0;
    function jump()
    {

    ball.posy -=10;
    limit++;


    if(limit>screenheight) 
    {
    //if character reached top of screen stop this jump() function
    isjump = false;
    limit = 0;
    }


    }
```

Above code will enable the character to jump up to the screen height. But if the screen height is smaller (for example, in some mobile device), character jump will be faster.
If there are any game developers who have idea, would you be able to guide me? :) Thank you.

Comment: I am not a game developer but I am an engeener and if your game resizes dependending of the resolution of the screen of course speed is going to change to since speed = distance / time , so if time is the same all is changing is the distance, becuse of screen resolution, you can change your timer intervar to an equivalent or fix distance

Comment: can you give some example solution please..I can understand speed = distance / time ..but dont know how to implement

Comment: yes I can, just I need some info, you can see your speed is faster 
because speed = 100px/10ms = 10px/ms then when it is in higer screen you get this speed = 200px/10ms = 20px/ms so speed is doubled I need to know what is the inteval of time you are using or the distance the character jumps

Comment: the problem is that 10 != 20 so its a simple math problem make those speeds be the same

Comment: i need something like character takes 3 seconds to jump and reach top  , no matter what screen height is

Comment: ok I will answer that

Comment: Sorry, it is a math problem, I am trying but maybe you need to study math it is an easy problem but you dont understand it

Comment: yea i understand speed velocity time..but unable to put that as code :(

Comment: what does function jump() does?, what I think it does is increase the heigth of the jump in 10px or some other fixed unit? am I rigth? something like actual jump + 10

Comment: it runs infinite loop according to browsers frame per second

Comment: actually...character will be in ground position.Function will increase the character position in Y axis with 10 pixel per microsecond

Comment: ok so you can NOT add always 10 pixels thats the problem ill try to explain and writte a solution

Comment: yea !! the loop runs till the character reach top of the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok the problem is that you need to know the speed of your jump first. now its is doing it depending of your screen for example:

```
function jump()
   myjump += 10 // this is what you are doing now
{
```

so lets fix that function, how? 
lets make that 10 variable depending on the screen height

lets say your screen now is 800px heigh so for a 800px height screen you will add 10px, but for a 400 heigth screen you only need to add 5px!!.

so how we do it?

with this simple formula

```
var scaleJump = 10 * (screenHeigth/800)

function jump()
   myjump += scaleJump
{
```

so now if your screen heigth is 800 your var scaleJump will be = 10 * ( 800 / 800 ) = 10

and if your screen heigth is 400 scaleJump will be = 10 * ( 400 / 800 ) = 5

so problem solved!! it will increase 5 if screen is 400 and 10 if screen is 800, and scale as needed if anyonther heigth

### to fix time

ok how do we know the time it takes to draw a frame?

```
since: fps = frames / second

so:   1/fps = seconds / frame
```

this is a differential equation where you have a deltaTime and a deltaDistance

DeltaTime is equals to:

```
1/fps
```

and DeltaDistance would be this, if fps were always the same, but like they are not I explain below:

```
10 * (screenHeigth/800)
```

now lets set a base speed wich you can change acording to your needs as I dont have your code I am not sure if this will move fast or slow, but you can test it and change it as you need it.

lets set speed to 1 (I dont know if it is fast or slow, just change it latter)

```
 since speed = DeltaDistance / DeltaTime
```

so lets get the distance you have to add so the speed is the same:

```
DeltaDistance = Speed * DeltaTime
```

now your code will look like this

```
var DeltaDistance;
var DeltaTime = (1 / fps)
var mySpeed = 1

function jump()
   DeltaDistance = mySpeed * DeltaTime
   myJump += DeltaDistance
{
```

I miss college :(

Comment: hey no  i want to limit the jump periods time :( .. please check http://photoapp.biz/test/node/res/ ..press anykey to jump..now resize window height and jump...it will jump very fast

Comment: ok in this example we fixed distance, the next update will fix time

Comment: yea please :) i tried setTimeout ,,but cant figure out how to implement

Comment: do you know the time it takes a jump() function?, it has to have an interval of time so you can match speeds. it if does know I recommend you to force it so you can match speeds

Comment: if each jump is a frame, so how many frames per secounds you draw?, I will make and example that depends of your frames per second

Comment: fps is calculated based on browser speed :( thats the problem

Comment: Ok but your code knows it, thats enough I will update

Comment: hey i got the code it it seems to jump up :) but while getting down..gravityspeed is same for all resolution

Comment: check my updated answer and base all your code to your speed, that will work

Comment: lol I know were the problem is, that speed stuff will help you if you are using physics like gravity, but the real problem is that if I rezise it vertically your monster is the same heigth, so it looks like it do it faster, but I am sure it is just a visual efect have you measure it? and of course it will be faster since monster is bigger, his body covers half of the distance....

Comment: no i fixed the problem , i resized monster when screen is resized..and am still testing your code :d

Comment: test it, but I almost sure that your rezise is wrong, because what I see in the animation, because I have no code :( is that when the head of your monser reach top it stopts jump() and is has not to be that way, because monser is not scaled vertically, just change that when the center of the monster reach top, and that will do the job

Comment: ok :) i will check..hey what is that with 800 ?? should it work on all screen ?

Comment: I recommend you to instead of that 800 use the resolution of your screen so now on every device will look like in your current screen

Comment: what you mean ? so its like var scaleJump = 10 * (screenHeigth/screenHeigth) ?

Comment: No, you are going to fix 800 and 10 , in simple words that means that for every 800px it will increase 10